# Datatables Rest filter count on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, datatable

I've got a SharePoint site that I'm running some Rest API queries on and filtering results.  I was just wondering if anyone had a quick tip on if its possible to pull a count from the following code snippit from a datatable

```
rowCallback: function(row, data){
if (data["RegistrationDate"] <= expiration.toISOString()){
    alert (the number of items that come back from this filter?);
    $('td:eq(6)', row).css('background-color', 'red');
}
else{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code, based on just that little snippet there, could you not initialize a counter variable somewhere outside of that function, and then inside that if statement (where you have your alert line), increment the counter?

There's probably a better way to do it wherever you get your REST responses back, but without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to say.

---

To address your comment - you're saying you're looking for a way "to filter the count inside the if statement", but I think that's the wrong way to look at it.  The `if` statement in your code snippet is inside the [DataTables `rowCallback` function](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback), which fires once for every row.  So at that point in the code, the `data` object really only represents one SharePoint list item (I'm assuming you are retrieving list items through a REST call to SharePoint and then passing those results to DataTables).  So you can't really "filter" per se at that point in code, because you don't have access to *all* the list items, you only have access to the one list item that's being put in that particular row.  That's why I suggested a counter, because the `rowCallback` function gets fired once for every item.  So it would be something like this:

```
// before you create the table, initialize a counter variable
var counter = 0;

// create the table, and the rowCallback will get fired once for every list item
$('#example').dataTable({
    "rowCallback": function (row, data) {
        if (data["RegistrationDate"] <= expiration.toISOString()) {
            $('td:eq(6)', row).css('background-color', 'red');

            // increment the count by one
            counter++;
        }
        else {
        }
    }
});
```

The better way to do it would be to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the results you get back from SharePoint before you create the table.  I can give you an example, but you will have to interpret how to work that into the existing code you have, without seeing your other code I can't really structure my example in a way that would naturally fit what you already have.  But see if this sparks any ideas:

```
$.ajax({
    url: your-url,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    // now you have your results
    var filteredResults = data.d.results.filter(function(item) {
        return item["RegistrationDate"] <= expiration.toISOString();
    });

    // now you have your count, before you make your table
    var count = filteredResults.length;

    // go ahead and make your table
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "rowCallback": function (row, data) {
            if (data["RegistrationDate"] <= expiration.toISOString()) {
                $('td:eq(6)', row).css('background-color', 'red');
            }
            else {
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I suppose I could run a completely separate ajax query and build the count there, That was one of the solutions I ran with but it makes for ugly code, i was just wondering if there was a quick easy way to filter the count inside the if statement and pass that variable up to my table.  Not a big deal, was just wondering if there was cleaner coding.  Sorry for the lack of code, I was hoping what i posted was sufficient to get the point across.  The network I'm writing all this on is a closed network and its hard to pass it back and forth, not as easy as a copy/paste to post the full code.

Comment: @Chuck.M updated my answer.

Comment: That did it.  When you mentioned running it outside the function i didn't know about the .filter function within the call.done. I was thinking run another ajax query with the filter built into Rest and then working with that count and that got really ugly.  I really appreciate you Dylan, you've helped me on a couple of these.  I really don't know much about what I'm doing so I'm very appreciative for your assistance

Comment: @Chuck.M absolutely no problem, I remember back when I was getting started and was trying to figure everything out, I relied on good answers in support forums like this.  So I'm just kind of paying it forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `ItemCount` property of the source list when querying for Items by modifying your REST call to include an expansion of the `ParentList` property

`https://site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/Items?$expand=ParentList`

This will add a `ParentList` object to each row of data returned, where `ParentList.ItemCount` is the total number of items in the list. Then you can fetch the value from e.g. `data[0].ParentList.ItemCount`

```
{
  "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
  "Id": 1,
  "ID": 1,
  "Modified": "2019-05-24T14:36:59Z",
  "Created": "2017-05-26T12:53:44Z",
  "AuthorId": 1,
  "EditorId": 1073741823,
  "OData__UIVersionString": "8.0",
  "Attachments": false,
  "GUID": "428bc81d-56fd-466a-8462-a844e2c736cd",
  "ParentList": {
    // peripheral data from the parent list (omitted)
    "ItemCount": 4983
  }
}
```

The downside of this is that you get a lot of extra data back with the request, which slows everything down. Therefore you should also consider using `$select` to return only the fields you need to use.

On the other hand, it's not too much effort to just issue an initial request for the sole purpose of getting the `ItemCount`. For example, I use this function (below) and put it in a `jQuery.when()` that, when resolved, returns the `ItemCount` property to the next function, which gets the List Items and also passes the ItemCount variable to the DataTables `deferLoading` setting.

```js
  // Just get the item count for the given list
  function getListItemCount(listId) {
    // wrap the whole thing in a deferred so we can use it in .when()
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

    // REST call 
    jQuery.ajax({
      "url": _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'" + listId + "')",
      "data": {
        // only return the ItemCount and nothing else
        "$select": "ItemCount"
      },
      "headers": {
        // return cleaner data by specifying 'nometadata'
        "accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata"
      }

    }).done(function (d) {
      // return the ItemCount to the next function
      dfd.resolve(d.ItemCount);
    }).fail(function (e) {
      dfd.reject(e);
    })

    return dfd.promise();
  }
```

**Usage** 
(`renderTable` accepts `ItemCount` as a parameter)

```js
    var listId = "5370628A-463B-4F87-8A60-BB54C628F708";
    jQuery.when(
      getListItemCount(listId)
    ).then(renderTable);
```

**Note**
I use `jQuery.when()` here but it would also work to just do:

```js
getListItemCount(listId).then(renderTable);
```

I decided to use `.when()` specifically because I want to implement other "preparatory" functions to get additional data before passing control to the `renderTable` function. For example, when using DataTables to render very large lists it is helpful to fetch several pages' worth of data up front, to reduce apparent loading time.